# AOP pointcut (using annotation) to log all methods except setters and getters from POJOs when using package by feature directory structure

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I am using AspectJ (AOP) for logging purpose. I have following package structure:

```
com.company.base

com.company.base.common.Result.java
(its a POJO containing 3 fields and their setters and getters and implements Serialize)

com.company.base.feature1.User.java
(its a POJO containing 5 fields and their setters and getters and implements Serialize)

com.company.base.feature2.Customer.java
(its a POJO containing 2 fields and their setters and getters and implements Serialize)
```

my requirement is:
1) log entry and exit messages when any method executes from any class except from POJO's setter and getter
2) minimum line of code should be there

I am using following pointcut definition but its also calling the advise at setters and getters time as well.

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.company.base..*(..))")
void allMethodExcution() {}
```

Please suggest as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got partial answer to my question (may be not the exact one).

1] All the POJOs are annotated with `@XmlRootElement` so I created one more pointcut and following advise

```
// join points created by following point cuts
@Pointcut("within(@javax...XmlRootElement *)")
public void beanAnnotatedWithSpecificAnnotation()

@Pointcut("execution(* com.company.base..*(..))")
public void allMethods()

// this is advise
@Before("!beanAnnotatedWithSpecificAnnotation() && allMethods()")
public void applyAdvise(JoinPoint jp) {
// TODO: advise code ...
}
```

2] But, what if POJO does not contain `@XmlRootElement` and only implements `java.io.Serialize` interface?